# Why filemove() can't use relative diretory

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using PB8.0. When I use `filemove()` to move a file to another directory, I use the relative directory like this:

```
filemove("\\test\test.csv","\\test1\test.csv")
```

but it returns -1, It means "Error opening sourcefile".

When i use the absolute directory, like

```
filemove("C:\Users\dell\Documents\test\test.csv","C:\Users\dell\Documents\test1\test.csv")
```

it is OK.

I want to know why I can't use relative directory in `filemove()`?

Comment: 1. The code you’ve listed isn’t relative to the current directory but the current drive (your file specification starts with a backslash). 2. Are you certain your current directory is what you think it is? Have you queried it? Windows does funny things with the “current directory”. Whether it supports relative paths or not, you should be careful with your expectations around where that relative path is starting from, especially if you expect that folder to remain constant throughout the run of the app. Some PB commands have been known to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use backslash. Use forward slash and nothing at the beginning of relative path:

```
filemove("test/test.csv","test1/test.csv")
```

[Source](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/BCGDEEIB.htm)